# Deleting empty rows generates 1004 error

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete rows, if cells in a certain column are empty.

I'm using the sample code I found [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/998727-macro-delete-rows-based-blank-cells-column.html).

Initially, the cells in question were in column B. I used the following:

```
Sub delrowEmptyStr()

    Dim EmpCol As Range, LstRw As Long
    LstRw = Columns(2).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
    Set EmpCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
    With Intersect(Rows("2:" & LstRw), EmpCol)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2="""",""X"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
        .SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

I reformatted and put that data in column A. I changed the Sub to the following:

```
Sub delrowEmptyStr()

    Dim EmpCol As Range, LstRw As Long
    LstRw = Columns(1).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
    Set EmpCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Offset(, 1).EntireColumn
    With Intersect(Rows("2:" & LstRw), EmpCol)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC1="""",""X"","""")"
        .Value = .Value
        .SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

Running this now yields '*Run-time error 1004: No cells were found*'.

Hitting 'Debug' highlights the row

```
.SpecialCells(xlConstants).EntireRow.Delete
```

I did sort my data differently before running the 2nd iteration of the Sub - I'm wondering if maybe having all the empty cells I want to get rid of to the bottom of the column may be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering if maybe having all the empty cells I want to get rid of to the bottom of the column may be the issue?

Yes, definitely, because the statement

> ```
> LstRw = Columns(1).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
>    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
> ```

yields the `LstRw` as the last non-empty row *in that specific column*. You can fix this by simply finding the last non-empty row in your whole sheet instead of the last non-empty row in the specific column:

```
'      vvvvvv
LstRw = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much, I figured it would be something simple but couldn't work out the _why_. Thanks for your effort!